# Is it possible to know if a header is included

Tags: c++, header

In the source code is it possible to know if a header is included?

This an example of what I need :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char headname[4];
    cout<<"Enter a header name : ";
    cin>>headname;

    #ifdef headname
        cout<<headname<<" Defined"<<endl;
    #else
        cout<<headname<<" Not defined"<<endl;
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

For example, if I enter "iostream", the output should be "iostream Defined".

Comment: `#ifdef` runs before compilation, definitely not during runtime.

Comment: any solution for the problem !! is what I want is possible !!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to know if a header is included. Just look at the top of your source file.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths or just struggle with errors, some of which might directly reveal that there's a missing header :D

Comment: @Paul Griffiths users can't see the top of of my source file ;) ... just read carefully the question :)

Comment: If users can't see your source file, then talking about whether headers are included is absolutely meaningless, since source files are the only thing they're ever included in. Think about your question more carefully.

Comment: @BBeta So, why would a user care if you have included a header as long as your code works?

Comment: please ... the question is clear is what I want possible yes or no that's all !!!!

Comment: The question is very unclear. You need to tell us WHY you need this - that's an important part of the question. There's simply no reason to know what includes any given .cpp file has included at any given line in code after compile time.

Comment: It's not unclear it's just of highly questionable utility. And impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Headers usually use include guards such as:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define MY_HEADER_INCLUDED

// [...]

#endif
```

On my Gentoo Linux / GCC system, looking at the iostream header I see:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM
#define _GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM 1
```

so you could check for `_GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM`. If you're not using GCC, open your `iostream` header file and see what macros they might have defined.

It should also be pointed out that `cout` belongs to the `iostream` header, so when `_GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM` (in my case) is not defined, the code will also fail to compile. But you can use `printf()` for the test.

Comment: But this would result in a compile time check (#ifdef) and not runtime.

Comment: `#ifdef` is a preprocessor directive. No use during runtime.

Comment: no simply someone will enter a header name and the program should tell him if this header exist ...

Comment: You're right, I did miss the "runtime" part. Well, the only way to check that a header exists in the system at runtime is to actually look up the header file in the include search path. But that will not tell you if that header has been #included when you built your program. That's a compile-time check.

Comment: You _could_ build a list of interesting headers at compile time, in a std::vector<std::string> for example: #ifdef HEADER1 you push_back() "HEADER1" to the list and so on. You could then check that one of those headers has been indeed #included at compile time at runtime. But that works only for a handful of headers, not _any_ included header.

Answer (score 0):

First off, checking for a header, "at runtime" and "at compile time" are no different since `#include` is executed at compile time along with any `#ifdef`. A `#include` essentially does a copy-paste of the header at the top of your .cpp file. Razvan Cojocaru pointed out that you can use the `#ifdef` to check weather `_GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM` is defined. Here is a little example of where this could be used:

```
class Flagger
{
    typedef unsigned long ulong;
    public:
        Flagger (ulong flags = 0)    : f(flags) { ; }
        Flagger (const Flagger& cpy) : f(cpy.f) { ; }

        void clear  (ulong flags) { f &= ~flags; }
        void set    (ulong flags) { f |= flags;  }
        void toggle (ulong flags) { f ^= flags;  }

        bool get    (ulong flags) { return f & flags; }

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_OSTREAM
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Flagger& f)
                { /* print it how you want it*/ }
#endif

    private:
        ulong f;
};
```

However, **this is probably a bad idea** for several reasons:

1. The user would need to include the above header after including iostream or the compiler would delete the function.
2. If at any point in time the makers of the iostream library decides to change the #define name, the function will be deleted. Likewise, if someone is using a different version of iostream with a different #define tag, the function is deleted.
3. In the above example, it is not too different to just include the library yourself. If some random user does not use the library, the final size of their program will not be much different and functionality will not have changed at all.

So basically, yes it is **possible**, but **not practical**. Especially for long-term maintenance. The benefits don't outweigh the danger. Just include the library in question yourself.

As stated by others here, it would be helpful if we knew what your final outcome is. The place you are planning to use this in most likely has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, A quick hack to do this is:

All you need to do is go to the source code header file. And access any member (any constant defined anywhere in source code of header file) via -

`cout<<ACCESSED_MEMBER`

now compile and run the program, if you got it printed on console then congrats, the file is included successfully in your code.

**Note:1** To find particular source file for header. you can type on terminal as

`locate <header_file_name>`
You will get the location of file. now check for any member by opening it in vi or nano or gedit or any editor of your choice.

**Note:2** Do not make any changes to this header file if it is not owned by you.

Answer (score -5):

Sure it's possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<std::string> includes;
    includes.push_back("iostream");
    includes.push_back("vector");
    includes.push_back("string");
    includes.push_back("algorithm");

    std::string user_input;
    std::cout << "Enter a header name: ";
    std::cin >> user_input;

    if ( std::find(includes.begin(), includes.end(), user_input) !=
            includes.end() ) {
        std::cout << user_input << " is included." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << user_input << " is not included." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$ ./incl
Enter a header name: iostream
iostream is included.
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$ ./incl
Enter a header name: map
map is not included.
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$
```

Comment: ummm...what's is this all about ? Not what OP asked

Comment: It does exactly what the OP asked, it enables the user of his program to check, at run time, what headers were included in the source.

Comment: The OP is under the illusion that it's possible to automate this process somehow. Which it isn't.

Comment: It's possible to automate this process in exactly the same way that it's possible to automate including the correct headers in the first place, so that shouldn't cause him any practical problems.

Comment: To be fair, there's the issue with nested includes. Still, this whole idea is mind-boggling to begin with. What about compiling with Unity? Precompiled headers? What's the purpose?

Comment: Not only the problem with nested includes, but also the problem of *which* include. Suppose the user wants to check for `#include "myheader.h"`. What if `myheader.h` includes a bunch of other includes now, but didn't when the program was compiled, and just contained the contents in the one file. Does he want to list them, or not? What if he has some completely different `myheader.h` that he'd like to check for? What if the executable was compiled from FORTRAN? The whole idea is totally nuts.